# How to restore Network backup to Network Path in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am trying to restore network backup file to network path.. is there any way to do it?

I am using SQL Server 2005 and code....

```
RESTORE DATABASE DB_NAme
FROM DISK = N'\\NetworkPath\backup_20140501030004.BAK'
WITH  FILE = 1
, MOVE 'DB_Data' TO '\\NetworkPath\DATA\DB.mdf'
, MOVE 'DB_Data2' TO '\\NetworkPath\DATA\DB_1.mdf'
, MOVE 'DB_Data3' TO '\\NetworkPath\DATA\DB_2.mdf'
, MOVE 'DB_Log' TO '\\NetworkPath\Log\DB_log.ldf'
, NOUNLOAD,REPLACE, STATS = 10;
```

Error:

> Msg 5110, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   The file "\NetworkPath\DATA\DB.mdf" is on a network path that is not supported for database files.
>   Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
>   File 'DB_Data' cannot be restored to '\NetworkPath\DATA\DB.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't believe you can restore an .MDF file to a network path. It has to be on the machine where SQL Server is running

Comment: Thanks for comment Mark, please check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491/restore-database-backup-over-the-network ... in my case i have to use both source and destination over network path

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has documented their "Description of support for network database files in SQL Server" at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304261

Trace flag 1807 bypasses the check and allows you to configure SQL Server with network-based database files. However, **this is not without risk** and you can fairly easily wind up with a corrupt database if the device does not fully support what SQL Server needs to achieve consistency.

If you want to use this approach in a manner that Microsoft will fully support, they have a set of standards describing what they support.  Following is a quote from the link:

**Windows Hardware Quality Lab (WHQL) qualified devices**
Microsoft Windows servers and networked servers or NAS storage servers that are Windows Hardware Quality Lab (WHQL) certified automatically meet the data write ordering and write-through guarantees required to support a SQL Server storage device. Microsoft supports both application and storage-related issues in these configurations.

**Note** To be supported by SQL Server, the NAS storage solution should also meet all the requirements that are listed on the following Microsoft website:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/E/8/6E882A06-B71B-4642-9EB4-D1EA0D6223C8/SQL%20Server%20IO%20Reliability%20Program%20Requirements%20Document.docx